# ZF3 - An event attached to the EventManager does not trigger

Tags: events, zend-framework, event-handling, zend-framework3

I have got an EntityRepository class and I want to attach an event to its "save" method. Here is the AbstractRepository class where I set identifier of the event manager:

```
abstract class AbstractRepository extends EntityRepository implements RepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EventManagerInterface
     */
    protected $events;

    /**
     * Set the event manager instance used by this context.
     *
     * @param EventManagerInterface $events
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function setEventManager(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        $events->setIdentifiers([
            __CLASS__,
            get_class($this),
        ]);

        $this->events = $events;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the event manager.
     *
     * Lazy-loads an EventManager instance if none registered.
     *
     * @return EventManagerInterface
     */
    public function getEventManager()
    {
        if (!$this->events) {
            $this->setEventManager(new EventManager());
        }

        return $this->events;
    }
}
```

and the repository class called DocumentRepository:

```
class DocumentsRepository extends AbstractRepository
{
    public function save(Documents $entity)
    {
        $this->getEventManager()->trigger(RepositoryInterface::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE);

        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($entity);
        $this->getEntityManager()->flush($entity);

        $this->getEventManager()->trigger(RepositoryInterface::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE);

        return $entity;
    }
}
```

Also an interface to define event names:

```
interface RepositoryInterface extends EventManagerAwareInterface
{
    const EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE   = 'before.save';
    const EVENT_AFTER_SAVE    = 'after.save';
}
```

To register the listener I added the following code to module.php.

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $application    = $event->getApplication();
    $eventManager   = $application->getEventManager();

    /* Register event listener(s) */
    (new DocumentsRepositoryListener($serviceManager))->attach($eventManager);
}
```

And finally, added the listener class:

```
class DocumentsRepositoryListener extends AbstractListener implements ListenerAggregateInterface
{
    public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events, $priority = 1)
    {
        $sharedEvents = $events->getSharedManager();

        $this->listeners[] = $sharedEvents
            ->attach(DocumentsRepository::class, RepositoryInterface::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE, [$this, 'beforeSave']);
        $this->listeners[] = $sharedEvents
            ->attach(DocumentsRepository::class, RepositoryInterface::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE, [$this, 'afterSave']);
    }

    public function detach(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        foreach ($this->listeners as $index => $listener) {
            if ($events->detach($listener)) {
                unset($this->listeners[$index]);
            }
        }
    }

    public function beforeSave(EventInterface $event)
    {
        /* Something to do before saving */
    }

    public function afterSave(EventInterface $event)
    {
        /* Something to do after saving */
    }
}
```

The class AbstractListener is also contains a constructor to inject serviceLocator and setter/getter methods.

Now, I don't know why the trigger doesn't work. Is there anything else which may be missed!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have written to *trigger* the events in `DocumentsRepository` has no issues. You have however a misunderstanding regarding the use of the event manager; specifically how you *attach* the event listeners.

The first point to make is that you have given the repository class is *own* instance of an `EventManager`; *this* is the instance that you should attach your event listeners to. The code in `Module::onBootstrap()` is registering with the *application* event manager,  which is the wrong instance. The application event manager deals with the application events and so it will never trigger your custom events.

```
/* Register event listener(s) */
(new DocumentsRepositoryListener($serviceManager))->attach($eventManager);
```

Would be replaced with :

```
$documentRepositoryListener->attach($repository->getEventManager());
```

The logic to register the listeners might be better suited in the `RepositoryFactory`, for example :

```
class RepositoryFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {       
        $repository = new Repository();

        if ($repository instanceof EventManagerAwareInterface) {
            $eventManager = $repository->getEventManager();
            $listener = $container->get('Foo/Event/Listener');

            $listener->attach($eventManager);
        }

        return $repository;
    }
}
```

Lastly, you will also need to remove the `$sharedEvents` usage in `DocumentsRepositoryListener::attach()`; as you want to attach event listeners to the repository event manager, which would be the `$events` argument.

Comment: What do you mean by $repository = new Repository() in the RepositoryFactory? Is it DocumentsRepository in my code?

Comment: @hamidGorashi Correct. The `RepositoryFactory` here is simply an example to show where/how you can register the events listeners in a factory; you can use this for any service that implements `EventManagerAwareInterface`.

Comment: Nice explanation @AlexP :) Small addition, if you're using `Foo::class => FooFactory::class` config to register Listener + Factory (under `service_manager > factories`), listeners would need to be enabled in the configuration under the `listeners` root config key. So in `module.config.php` an entry: `'listeners' => [Foo::class,],`.